# Weird sqlite problems. Not inserting/updating consistant values, from variables and args

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've been running into quite a few database problems lately. My current situation is that a record is not created with the the value I tell it to. It creates "00" instead of "100". The weird thing is that this only happens in the android emulator. The device i'm using (Driod Incredible) runs the same code fine. However, I have not looked at the database on the phone, because eclipse does not open the data folder for some reason. I only discovered this when i decided to pull the database from emulator(because of other sqlite issues that i am having please look at my other questions if you are proficient in this area) . I got a force close earlier than expected from a cursor index error, index size of 0. This is because the value i'm looking for is 100 and it was created as 00. Whats the dill?

```
public void createEmptyProfile(String SaveSlot) {
 ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    //ITEM 100
    initialValues.put(ITEM, "100");
    initialValues.put(VALUE1, "100");
    initialValues.put(SAVE_SLOT, SaveSlot);
    initialValues.put(CATEGORY, "S");
    mDb.insert(DATABASE_PUSHERS_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    initialValues.clear();
    //ITEM 99       
    initialValues.put(ITEM, "99");
    initialValues.put(VALUE1, "0");
    initialValues.put(SAVE_SLOT, SaveSlot);
    initialValues.put(CATEGORY, "S");
    mDb.insert(DATABASE_PUSHERS_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    initialValues.clear();
return;
```

the database has item 99, but item 00 instead of 100. All other values are correct. There are numerous items.

table create:

```
"create table profiles (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        "save_slot text not null,item text, value1 text, " +
        "value2 text, category text);"
```

Comment: I'm creating several profiles that will have a set of items that will be updated repeatedly according to which profile is selected. The profile requires several initial items and values. Items are updated based on user input and math.

Comment: I mean what is your .schema for the create table statement?

Comment: you mean the the create statement? made an edit above

Comment: what happens if you put 1000 as a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a single quote and that fixed it.

from

```
initialValues.put(ITEM, "100");
```

to

```
initialValues.put(ITEM, "'100'");
```